# SQL: Auditing changes to object with multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Cheques table and a Purchase Orders table with a one-to-many relationship. (Each Cheque has n Purchase Orders, each Purchase Order has 1 or zero Cheques)
Users will typically add a Cheque to a Purchase Order and then modify the Cheque details. On occasion they will later remove the Cheque from the PO and add a different one.

I want to track all changes to Cheques and Purchase Orders, and display the audit trail on demand. A typical audit trail looks like this:

- PO Details changed by (userName) on (date). Changed field1 from x to y, field2... etc
- PO Details changed by (userName) on (date). Changed field1 from x to y, field2... etc
- Added cheque xxxx to PO (username, date, etc)
- Changed cheque xxxx details etc etc
- Removed cheque xxxx
- Added cheque yyyy to PO
- Changed cheque yyyy details...

I'm trying to work out how to track changes to the tables in a normalised way. When the user changes a cheque's details, the audit trail on **all** the POs with that cheque will show the change. But the audit trail should only show changes to the cheque that occurred **while** the cheque was attached to the PO in question.

Consider an approach where I have ChequeAudit and POAudit tables, and store a row in these tables each time something in the base table changes. Now in order to present the user with a list of changes to a Purchase Order, I can return all the rows concerning the PO itself, and in addition, all the rows concerning any cheques that have ever been on the PO. But then I'd need to exclude rows concerning changes to a cheque that were made before the cheque was added to the PO, or after the cheque was removed from the PO. And a straight up join on the date interval won't work, since a cheque can be attached and removed again, any number of times.

I haven't worked out a way to store a single entry in the cheque change log and easily link it back to the purchase order(s). Specifically, what database structure do I need in order to query a PO, and return all the changes made to any cheques that occurred **while** the cheque was attached to the PO? Can this be normalised, or am I forced to log a single change to a cheque's details against every single associated PO?

Comment: what is the data structure Trent ? :)

Answer (score 2):

I would define one audit table for POs, and another audit table for Cheques. Logging options include:

1. Adding the `OUTPUT` clause to your INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE statements,
   as I demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9243389/sql-server-2005-knowing-new-record-is-inserted).
2. DML Triggers are another common way log updates to audit tables. While I gave an example of a trigger [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9511158/autoincrementing-alphanumeric-id-for-a-table-based-on-unique-id-of-another-table/9511547#9511547), a more in-depth discussion can be found on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258254%28v=sql.80%29.aspx).

As a footnote, I would add that you are hopefully using stored procedures to manage all of your DML chores.

Comment: It's trivial to audit changes to either of the tables involved. The problem I have is in the last paragraph of my post. I've edited my post for clarity

Comment: Where your last paragraph says "while the cheque was attached," I envision a nullable foreign key linking cheques to POs. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, the foreign key can be null (no attached cheque).

Comment: I would consider using a DML trigger on the cheques table that builds a historical cross reference table  between Cheques and POs (in addition to your existing audit). The cross reference table should also include a timestamp column. This should establish the moment-in-time relationship history between POs and cheques that you require.